# Loading data from text file into ListView

Tags: android, file, listview, text

I have just started studying android programming. I have a problem that I hope someone can help to solve it.
it is:
I have a `ListView` and a text file name is `contact.txt` with content in below:

```
John Mesk,0155044932<br>
Lisa Mohamlise,0155044932<br>
Behney Comus,055653333<br>
```

how to load data from it into `ListView`? I saved the text file to drawable/contact.txt
Thank you for reading!

Comment: if that's it, then read the .txt to string, then go through the strings and add them to an array..then populate your listview.. but add commas, at then end of every contact number.. to make things easier

Comment: my code:
`code`
if(in!=null){
  try {
    while((line=buff.readLine())!=null){
     str=line.split(",");
     //contact.add(str)
    }
    
   } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
  }

  adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, str);
  list.setAdapter(adapter);
`code`

Answer (score 0):

**I got your Details**

To read the file to string..there are soo many ways from **1**

`String text = new Scanner( new File("contact.txt") ).useDelimiter("\\A").next();`

to **2** Commons [FileUtils.readFileToString](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#readFileToString%28java.io.File%29), and also you go do **3**

```
static String readFile(String path, Charset encoding) 
 throws IOException{
 byte[] encoded = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(path));
 return new String(encoded, encoding);
}
```

or if better still you could place em in line breaks or newline and do some slick one like this **4**

```
List<String> contacts = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(path), encoding);
```

for more [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.charset.Charset%29)

**Character encoding is** = `StandardCharsets.UTF_8`

so depending on your choice, implement one of them. for illustrations i use the last one, and since i got my lines i do some slick one like this

```
Listview.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Context,yourResourcelayout, contacts));
```

yeah i think is done.. let me know if its helpful

Comment: hello Sir @HoGiang quick question, did the answer help you solve it? if so then accept it, so the question goes unanswered..